# Sort UIView subviews z-order based on position

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, uiview

I have a `UIView` with a bunch of subviews. I'd like to sort the z-order of all the subviews based on their y position (frame.origin.y), such that:

if (view1.frame.origin.y > view2.frame.origin.y) --> view1 has higher z-order than view 2.

I could just remove all the subviews, sort them using `sortedArrayUsingComparator` and re-add them all in the correct order. However, that would cause a flicker and my goal is to sort them all without removing them from the superview. I'm guessing this could be accomplished using a sort algorithm plus `exchangeSubviewAtIndex` however I'm stuck on implementing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in order to do this I suggest setting tags to your views when they are initialised so we can find them easily later.

Here we are going to add the views y coordinates into a dictionary and give the key as the views tag. Assuming these are your only subviews with tags. Otherwise have a system to omit tags.

```
// Setting views and frames.

NSMutableDictionary *dict   = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *keyArray    = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {

    if (view.tag) {

        [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:view.frame.origin.y] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:view.tag]];

    }

}
```

Iterate through the dictionary and insert the y values in a descending order.

```
for (NSNumber *keyNum in [dict allKeys]) {

    float x = [[dict objectForKey:keyNum] floatValue];

    int count = 0;

    if (floatArray.count > 0) {

        for (NSNumber *num in floatArray) {

            float y = [num floatValue];

            if (x < y) {

                count++;

                [floatArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:x] atIndex:count];
                [tagArray insertObject:keyNum atIndex:count];

                break;
            }

        }

    }else{

        [floatArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:x] atIndex:count];
        [tagArray insertObject:keyNum atIndex:count];

    }
}
```

Get your views back using their tags and position the views by iterating through each one and using the bringSubViewToFront method, This should stack them in the correct order.

Note: This assumes you have not got other subviews in your view that need to on top of the hierarchy, if so I would use insertSubview: AtIndex: method.

```
for (NSNumber *num in tagArray) {

    UIView *view = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:[num integerValue]];

    NSLog(@"view.frame.origin.y: %.2f",view.frame.origin.y);

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:view];

}
```

Comment: I didn't use this exact solution, but the concept of looping through the sorted array and bringing that subivew to front solved the problem for me. Marking correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I used for this was:

```
NSArray *arraySorted = [self.subviews sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {

    NSComparisonResult result = NSOrderedSame;

    if ([obj1 isKindOfClass:[MySubView class]] && [obj2 isKindOfClass:[MySubView class]]) {

        MySubView *pin1 = (MySubView *)obj1;
        MySubView *pin2 = (MySubView *)obj2;

        result = pin1.frame.origin.y > pin2.frame.origin.y ? NSOrderedDescending : NSOrderedAscending;

    }

    return result;

}];

for (UIView *subview in arraySorted) {
    [self bringSubviewToFront:subview];
}
```